# Matlab eigs function with function handle

Tags: matlab, eigenvalues, documentation

I am reading through the documentation of matlab function `eigs` specifically the function handle input version.

Here it is: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eigs.html#bu2_q3e-Afun

I don't understand what this function is supposed to do. Does anybody know? I have a piece of matlab code not written by me which uses it but I don't understand it.

Maybe is a simple thing, but I don't understand it. My specific question is what is the function handle supposed to represent?

Comment: This type of question is probably better suited to ask on a Matlab specific forum. In any case, what case do you not understand from the documentation you shared?  The list gives four specific specifications for what the function passed as a function handle should do in relation to the matrix A for which eigenvalues are desired. The example shows how to do this for the second case in the list of possibilities.

Comment: It isn't clear what the function handle is supposed to represent. I guess is like an update rule but it isn't clear on that.

Comment: It's not really an update handle. With this approach you don't need to form the matrix/linear operator and only need to have a function defining how it transforms  an arbitrary vector x.  For example the first variant, the function should return the vector y = Ax when using the first variant explained in the documentation. This can save memory/computation time with the methods Lutz Lehman and Bill Green describe in their answers. The function handle is used internally in the algorithm instead of a matrix.

Answer (score 4):

This is for algorithms like Lanzcos-Arnoldi or Krylov-Schur, as mentioned in the reference part of the documentation page. Generally these are Krylov-space generalizations of the power iteration, inverse power iteration and shifted-inverse power iteration.

Comment: Matlab cites this article for example [1] Stewart, G.W. "A Krylov-Schur Algorithm for Large Eigenproblems." SIAM Journal of Matrix Analysis and Applications. Vol. 23, Issue 3, 2001, pp. 601–614.

Comment: Thanks, I did not directly copy the algorithm name.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't reacting to the names you used :-) .  I was just adding it for context as it seems @user8469759 may actually be most interested in the algorithm itself and not what the function handle is per se.

Answer (score 3):

The non-function handle version of the eigs function
assumes that the A-matrix (and optionally the B-matrix) are
defined as matlab sparse matrices and operated on using
matlab sparse matrix functions.

The function handle version allows you to use to your own
reprsentation for sparse matrices and perform the operations
required by the eigs function using your own functions.
In fact, using this option means that you do not necessarily
have to explicitly form the A-matrix at all-- you can calculate
terms of the product $a_{ij}\times x_j$ piece-by-piece. For very large
systems, this can save a huge amount of storage space. (In the
area of iterative, sparse matrix solvers, this is often referred
to as a "matrix-free" approach.)

Comment: But what is the meaning of the return types? The documentation mentions to return very specific operations done on a vector x.

Comment: The returned argument is the vector result of particular operation eigs requests your function to perform.

Comment: To do what? I think, as I said, is the purpose of the function handle in don't understand. Is it maybe a specific step in the algorithm maybe?

Comment: The eigs function is simply a matlab interface to the ARPACK library which is extensively documented, e.g. Lehoucq, R.B., D.C. Sorenson, and C. Yang. ARPACK Users' Guide. Philadelphia, PA: SIAM, 1998.

Comment: @user8469759 The function handle is the object that performed the transformation $x\to Ax$. Often times it is preferable for large problems to try and work with algorithms that only require this matrix-vector product instead of having to form the entire matrix $A$ in memory. This is particularly true for sparse matrices and discretized differential equations